# How to pass modify value to user define output file using Tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I have text file which contains some values I want pass that values to output.csv files through TCL script but I'm not able to pass values to output file and it is passing as it is values to output file.

Data /usr/local/test/etc/file.txt

```
value=$test1
value1=$test2
value2=$test2
```

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh

set test1 A
set test1 B
set test1 C

set fileN "output.csv"
set mdata_file [open [file join "/usr/out/input" $fileN] a]
set sql_file [open "/usr/local/test/etc/file.txt" r]
set sql_query [read $sql_file]
puts $mdata_file $sql_query
exit 0
```

I'm getting output like this in output.csv

```
value=$test1
value1=$test2
value2=$test2
```

But output should be like below

```
value=A
value1=B
value2=C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
puts $mdata_file $sql_query
```

to

```
puts $mdata_file [subst $sql_query]
```

The `subst` command performs substitutions on a string. Unless it is used, the exact contents of the input file are copied to the output file.

You probably want to change

```
set test1 A
set test1 B
set test1 C
```

to

```
set test1 A
set test2 B
set test3 C
```

and `value2=$test2` to `value2=$test3` also.

Documentation: [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `puts $mdata_file $sql_query`
try `puts $mdata_file [subst $sql_query]`

See the documentation of [subst command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm).

You also have a few typos to clean up - repeating test1 or test2 instead of using test1 test2 test3.